# aligning text in vim according to whitespace using tabularize plugin

Tags: vim

I'm trying to align the following text in vim using [tabularize](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular):

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int *pa;
    float b;
    float *pb;
    double c;
    double *pc;
} foo_t;
```

to this:

```
typedef struct {
    int    a;
    int    *pa;
    float  b;
    float  *pb;
    double c;    /* notice there's only one space between 'double' and 'c' */
    double *pc;
} foo_t;
```

I tried using `:'<,'>Tab/.*\s` but it leaves two spaces between `double` and `c`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
:'<,'>Tabularize /\S\+;$/l1
```

- `/\S\+;$/` pattern: make `a;`,`*pa;`...`*pc;` as column separators.
- `l1` flag: make every column `left` alignment and `one` space after it. (Not required here, because it's a default behavior)

Comment: it worked as well as adding an `l0` flag to my first trial. I didn't know about those flags, should have read the doc, thanks..